# Is changing the theme will affect the extensions in magento2?

Tags: magento2, theme, upgrade

Today i had purchased the new theme for my store. I want to change the theme but i'm afraid on my extensions will had a problem or not.

I'm a beginner in magento2. Also, currently my store magento version is 2.2.2 and i want to upgrade the store to 2.2.6(latest version). Please anyone clear my doubts in detail. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option is set up the magento latest version locally and install your theme in that environment. Then you can do the testing.

Or you can check the release notes and find the compatibility.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/bk-release-notes.html

Comment: that is not possible. since Database is large and have to configure extensions.. anyway thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on the theme, if the theme overrides or interacts with any of the module files it will affect it else it won't.

For example if a module makes a change to fileA.phtml, but your theme has removed or modified fileA.phtml there may be problems.

Comment: how to know/find the interacted files of the theme with module.?

Comment: You'll need to look at the code in the module and see what files it changes, then see if your theme has changed any of the same files.The easiest way would be to install the theme and see if the module still works.